# Relation between integrals of absolute value cosine and sine of a multiple angle in a fraction period

Tags: definite-integrals, absolute-value, periodic-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I have problems proving the following statement:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{2 \pi}{n}}\left|\cos \left(\frac{n}{2} x\right)\right| d x=\int_{0}^{\frac{2 \pi}{n}} \left| \sin \left(\frac{n}{2} x\right)\right| d x=\frac{4}{n}$$

The second equality is clear to me because it is straightforward integration:
$$\left.\int_{0}^{\frac{2 \pi}{n}}\left|\sin \left(\frac{n}{2} x\right)\right| d x=\int_{0}^{\frac{2 \pi}{n}} \sin \left(\frac{n}{2} x\right) d x=\frac{-\cos \left(\frac{n}{2} x\right)}{\frac{n}{2}}\right]_{0}^{\frac{2 \pi}{n}}=\frac{4}{n}$$

However, I don't know how to prove it analytically with $\displaystyle \left|\cos \left(\frac{n}{2} x\right)\right|$ because the absolute value changes in the integration domain.

Comment: The standard way to deal with that is to divide the integral into two at the point $x=\frac\pi n$ where the absolute value changes. You'll then be able to do both integrals individually like you did the sin integral.

Comment: That seems reasonable, I was trying to get from sin to cosine just by change of variable and identities, but I had achieved nothing.

Comment: It's useful to note that changes of variable of the form $x\mapsto c\pm x$ never change the *values* of the integrand, just where they occur; so those changes of variable would never circumvent this particular issue.

Comment: I will definitely take that into account!